# Inline Html Elements

Tags: html, css

I want to display text and button on the same line, i have tried several ways, also i have searched through internet resources and also viewed many questions on the similar topic on stack overflow. Here is my code..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <div>Text Here<button id="button" style="float:right">Click Me!</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Output of above written code:
[image: Here is the Output of above written code...]

Comment: If we render your code, the button looks inline with the text!

Comment: post the css what you have written..

Comment: If you remove the float:left the button will render inline, unless there's some other css affecting it (which seems likely because it is styled in your screenshot.

Comment: Actually i'm not good at Css, i think @SilentVoid you are right, style sheet is effecting it.

Comment: Find your button's `height` (50px), then set this **height** onto the parent **div**'s height and line-height: `<div style="height: 50px; line-height: 50px;">Text Here<button id="button" style="float:right">Click Me!</button></div>`

Comment: Yeah got it! Thanks @dNitro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <div>Text Here
   <button id="button"  style="float: 'right'">Click Me!</button>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above works. You've missed the ''.

Edited - added -

It does work when you apply other styles, for instance:

```
<html>
<body>
   <div style="color:blue;text-align:center; background-color:red">Text Here
   <h1 style="color:blue;text-align:center">This is a header</h1>
   <button id="button"  style="float: 'right'">Click Me!</button>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What would you like to do exactly? Try explaining or maybe drawing, sketching somehow for us to help you.

Comment: I have added some information to the post, to respond to this question.

Comment: Thanks I have found the solution.. :)

Comment: @MoizHusnain I am glad!

Answer (score 1):

Referring to all the answers here is the final solution to this problem...
I'm answering this for those who will refer this question in future, Thanks to all :)

```css
.Data
{
   display: inline;
   display: inline;
   line-height: 30px;
   height: 30px;
}
.DataButton
{
   float:right;
   font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 20px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   cursor: pointer;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   transition-duration: 0.4s;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
   background-color: white; 
   color: black; 
   border: 2px solid #00AABB;
   height: 30px;
}
.DataButton:hover {
    background-color: #00AABB;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="Data">
      Text Here!
      <button class="DataButton">Click Me!</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop using floats.
Here is your code.

```
<div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">Text Here<button id="button">Click Me!</button></div>
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @MoizHusnain well, you should share it with us.

Answer (score 0):

block elements in html are by default display:block. 
The best way to show them in one line is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>
            <div><p style="display: inline;">Text Here</p><button id="button">Click Me!</button></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: or this:

<div><p style="float:left;">Text Here</p><button id="button">Click Me!</button></div>

if this didn't work then there must b something else breaking your code. 
what exactly you wanna show?

Comment: It's Actually a research project related to automation and control and this page will be used to read current state of controls as reported by sensors, this page is going to be generated autonatically, i'm actually good at back end but not at front end, that's why i'm having problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use display flex. Moreover you should add text in a  tag and then add `float:left;` for label and `float:right;` for button.